# Is it possible to disable a dismissible in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm building an imageviewer which is built on an `InteractiveViewer`.  The `InteractiveViewer` is wrapped in a `Dismissible` that will dismiss the widget when the image is swiped up.

```
        Listener(

          onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent event) {

            if (_transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis() > 1.0) {       
                     _canBeDismissed = false; }
            else { _canBeDismissed = true;  }

          },
          child: AnimatedOpacity(
            opacity:_opacity,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            child: Dismissible(
              //direction: DismissDirection.vertical,
              direction: (_canBeDismissed == true) ? DismissDirection.vertical : DismissDirection.vertical,
              key: daKey,
              onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onDoubleTapDown: _handleDoubleTapDown,
                onDoubleTap: _handleDoubleTap,
                child: InteractiveViewer(
                  transformationController: _transformationController,
                  child:
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image:
                      DecorationImage(
                        image:
                        CachedNetworkImageProvider(image),
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
```

However, when the image is zoomed in and a user tries to pan the image, it will dismiss the image rather then let the user pan the image.

So I was thinking of simply disabling the Dismissible while an image is zoomed.  I can detect when an image is zoomed by using a `Listener`, and setting my variable `_canBeDismissed` to true or false-- that is not a problem.

The problem is how do I programmatically disable the dismissible function?

I tried to mess with the dismiss `direction` and have it set to `null` as follows:

```
direction: (_canBeDismissed == true) ? DismissDirection.vertical : null,
```

But I guess you aren't allowed to set it to null so that didn't work.  I was hoping there is some kind of `enabled` flag that would solve my problems.  Any ideas?  Or alternative ways of accomplishing my ultimate goal which is to have a image widget that a user can zoom and pan but also dismiss by swiping up, similar to twitter.  (I've already tried some of the big repositories on pub.dev but they all seem buggy or are impossible to implement)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can disable by setting direction like this,

```
direction: DismissDirection.none
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `confirmDismiss` parameter to veto the dismissal.

Example:

```
Dismissible(
  confirmDismiss: (direction) async => _canBeDismissed,
  child: // ...
),
```

Comment: error: The return type 'bool' isn't a 'Future<bool?>', as required by the closure's context.

Comment: Right, I forgot an async there. Just edited my original response.